# When does $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^x f(x') dx'=x \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$?

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, mathematical-physics

Under what conditions do the following relation holds?
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^x f(x') dx'=x \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$
Should it be stated that $f(0)=0$?

Let's say that I know the primitive function of $f$ when integrated on $x$:
$\int f(x) dx=F(x)$.
Then, I have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^x f(x') dx'= \frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial F(0)}{\partial t}$$
which I don't know how to compute.

Comment: In what variables does $f$ stand? Is $f=f(x)$ or $f= f(x,t)$?

Comment: $f=f(x)$, no $t$ dependence.

Answer (score 0):

As written, the integral on the left does not involve $t$, so the LHS is identically zero. So the RHS must also be identically zero, and $f$ must be constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an application of [Leibnitz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). It is sometimes also known as [Differentiation under the Integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Using this, you can easily obtain the following:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^x f(x') dx'= \frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial F(0)}{\partial t}$$